# Are "orange" and "ginger" synonymous (cat color)?

Tags: word-choice, slang, dialects, historical-change, colors

I recently watched a movie [*A street cat named Bob*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Street_Cat_Named_Bob_(film)), where the cat was described as *ginger cat*.

I thought the color of the cat is described as *orange*, too. (confirmed with [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Orange%20cat&hl=ja_JP&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1750&bih=956&ei=RCyRY_uJGY-D0wSW1IKQDg&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY5E6VHquxdQCDJhCM63X3mkbMnmKH1n_&ved=0ahUKEwj7u9vN3uj7AhWPwZQKHRaqAOIQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=Orange%20cat&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBwgAEAQQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeOgoIABAEEIAEELEDOg0IABAEEIAEELEDEIMBOggIABCABBCxA1CZCljQI2C6J2gAcAB4AIAB3gGIAZsKkgEFMi43LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ7ABAA&sclient=img))

The Cambridge dictionary has [the following](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ginger?q=Ginger)

> ginger noun (PERSON)
> [ S ] UK offensive
> a person who has red or orange-brown hair:

> ginger adjective (COLOUR) 
> having a red or orange-brown colour:
>
> His nickname was Ginger because of his ginger hair.
> a ginger cat

So the title of the question: are those two are synonymous as cat color? Extra questions are

- Is either more common?
- Is either more British?
- Does either have additional nuances?

Comment: ginger hair or coat is more BrE. In AmE, we'd say orange cat but most AmE speakers know ginger is orange. Then there's: Orlando the Marmalade Vat [haha] Lots of fun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_(fictional_cat)

Comment: "Until recently, the gene responsible for the ginger or marmalade cat was known as yellow but the standard designation is now orange." Roy Robinson; *Genetics for Cat Breeders*, Second ed., 1977. I think it's fine to use any of the terms for cats.

Comment: @DjinTonic Wikipedia says [This color is known as red by breeders.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_coat_genetics#Sex-linked_orange/red), just like in [red foxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_fox) and [robin redbreast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_robin) and [redheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair). :-)

Comment: @tchrist Yes, it does, under "Sex-linked orange/red" and continues "Other names include yellow, ginger, and marmalade." Perhaps the cat fanciers among us can chime in as to what they say; it may vary cat to cat depending on the expression.

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I've never heard of an 'orange cat', though I'm aware that Americans find the term 'ginger' puzzling.

Comment: "Ginger" for hair is probably more common in the UK, but ginger hair is more common in the UK (especially in certain parts). There are a lot of terms for cat colours, some of which are standardised by cat-showing organisations, some of which aren't. What is common among cat breeders is unlikely to be what is common among people who don't own cats.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree with you but, of course, Bob and his human are both British. (See the Big Issue)

Comment: What's interesting is that even though Americans don't use "ginger" for cat colors, we're very familiar with it for human redheads. But human red hair is a very different set of shades than orange cats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a difference between Britain and the US in the everyday use of the terms *ginger* and *orange* to refer to the colour of cats. Like some of the British commenters, I have never heard the term orange used to describe cats, and the google ngrams bear out the predominance of [*ginger cat* in British published work](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ginger+cat%2C+orange+cat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) and [orange cat in the US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ginger+cat%2Corange+cat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3).

That’s the factual stuff over with, now for the subjective and interpretive part of the answer. If you look at the ngrams, you will see that these terms seem to date from the 1930s in Britain, and 30 years later in the US. My own mental association of the adjective, *ginger*, with cats is in the expression:

> the ginger **tom**

which an ngram search indicates is of similar vintage in Britain, and only appears in the US this century. I would suggest that this term — which already existed in popular parlance — was popularized by its use in the catch-phrase [“the ginger tom from next door”](https://euroweeklynews.com/2021/11/25/catchphrases/) in the British Radio program [“Ray’s a Laugh”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Ray_(comedian)) that ran in the 1950s. I remember it well.

From a sociological point of view, I wonder whether there is/was any difference in the ubiquity of cats between the working class terrace housing in Britain — where neighbourhood cats were abundant — and the situation in the US. I always associated the term ‘marmalade’ found in children’s books of the more affluent 1970s with the more genteel South English middle classes. I never heard it in my own youth in the back streets of a Northern industrial city.